# vertical offset in plot - ggplot and geom_line

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to provide some value to `ggplot` to provide some vertical offset between `geom_line`s in a plot.

For example:

```
library(tidyverse)
mwe <- as_tibble(seq(-5,5,0.5))
mwe <- mwe %>% mutate(p1=dnorm(value,mean=0,sd=0.5), p2=dnorm(value,mean=0,sd=1.0), p3=dnorm(value,mean=0,sd=1.5))
mwe <- mwe %>% gather(p1:p3, key="p", value = "int")

mwe %>% ggplot(aes(x=value, y=int, colour=p)) + geom_line()
```

[image: three overlapping gaussians]

Can I provide some position statement to provide a constant offset (or maybe a vector of offsets) between the plots so I can manually minimise their overlap? In this particular case, I'd leave p3 where it is, move p2 up about 0.1, and p3 up about 0.3.

The inbuilt position option seems only to provide dodge capacity in the x direction. I don't really want to have to precompute the offsets in the data.

Comment: I know it's not what you want, but I think the closest solution might be to use faceting, e.g. `facet_grid(rows = vars(value))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little bit unorthodox and I'm not sure this is what the intended use case is, but you can use the delayed evaluation mechanics from ggplot2 v3.3.0 to nudge groups.

Note that `group` is a calculated variable in the case below that takes on integer values, so this `group` variable would follow the group set in `colour`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
mwe <- as_tibble(seq(-5,5,0.5))
mwe <- mwe %>% mutate(p1=dnorm(value,mean=0,sd=0.5), 
                      p2=dnorm(value,mean=0,sd=1.0), 
                      p3=dnorm(value,mean=0,sd=1.5))
mwe <- mwe %>% gather(p1:p3, key="p", value = "int")

mwe %>% ggplot(aes(x = value, colour=p)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = stage(int, after_stat = y + c(0, 0.1, 0.3)[group])))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: That looks like it will do exactly what I'm after. I'll have to check it out after breakfast. Where can I find out about ggplot's calculated variables?

Comment: By default, a group and panel is always calculated. You can read about the groups in `?aes_group_order`. Then, layers with a stat have extra calculated variables, which you can see in the stat's documentation; see e.g. `?stat_density` the section 'computed variables'.